# How to join rules and print out outputs in prolog

Tags: prolog

I have list of facts as follows.

```
items(itemId('P01'),prodName('Pots'),stockQty(50),price(8200)).
items(itemId('P02'),prodName('Pans'),stockQty(50),price(400)).
items(itemId('P03'),prodName('Spoons'),stockQty(50),price(200)).
items(itemId('P04'),prodName('Forks'),stockQty(50),price(120)).
items(itemId('P05'),prodName('Kettles'),stockQty(50),price(500)).
items(itemId('P06'),prodName('Plates'),stockQty(50),price(60)).
```

How to print on the console something like the following when a command like `print_all_products.` is given.

> ..............
>
> Available Products
>
> ..........
>
> Name         Qty
>
> Pots         60
>
> Pans         50
>
> Spoons       40
>
> ..................

- The Name and Qty must be properly formatted in a tabular structure.

I tried using `forall` and `foreach` I am unsuccessful in generating what i need.

Comment: In other programming languages printing what looks like a business report of the data is common and your output looks like a business report. In Prolog I rarely format my output to look like a business report as that is not why I use Prolog. If you are trying to learn Prolog then learn to use Prolog for what it is great at and don't try and use it to do what you do with other programming languages because that is what you know. Free your mind of the concepts of other programming languages and learn Prolog from the ground up. Continued.

Comment: Put another way, learning to be great at Prolog is not easy if you make it hard. If you want to make learning Prolog even harder then try an learn to use Prolog wrong from the start and then spend several times more effort unlearning the wrong way to use Prolog to get great at Prolog.

Comment: Oh ok. Apart from the report like structure isn't it good to learn how to print out a list of all the available values out ?

Comment: @GuyCoder could you check this out. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63324062/how-to-print-out-all-the-facts-in-prolog. I have simplified the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer with more details is posted [here](https://swi-prolog.discourse.group/t/so-answer-to-printing-tabular-report-using-forall-2-or-foreach-2/2793?u=ericgt).
Below is the code so that this is not a link only answer.

```
items(itemId('P01'),prodName('Pots'),stockOty(50),price(8200)).
items(itemId('P02'),prodName('Pans'),stockOty(50),price(400)).
items(itemId('P03'),prodName('Spoons'),stockOty(50),price(200)).
items(itemId('P04'),prodName('Forks'),stockOty(50),price(120)).
items(itemId('P05'),prodName('Kettles'),stockOty(50),price(500)).
items(itemId('P06'),prodName('Plates'),stockOty(50),price(60)).

header("\n........................\nAvailable Products\n........................\nName   Qty\n").
footer("........................\n").

spaces(Length,Spaces) :-
    length(List,Length),
    maplist([_,0'\s]>>true,List,Codes),
    string_codes(Spaces,Codes).

padded_string(String,Width,Padded_string) :-
    string_length(String,String_length),
    Padding_length is Width - String_length,
    spaces(Padding_length,Padding),
    atom_concat(String,Padding,Padded_string).

format_detail_line(item(Name,Quantity),width(Name_width),Formatted_item) :-
    padded_string(Name,Name_width,Padded_name),
    atom_concat(Padded_name,Quantity,Formatted_item).

add_detail_line(width(Name_Width),Item,Lines0,Lines) :-
    format_detail_line(Item,width(Name_Width),Formatted_item),
    atomic_list_concat([Lines0,Formatted_item,"\n"], Lines).

items_detail(Detail) :-
    findall(item(Name,Quantity),items(_,prodName(Name),stockOty(Quantity),_),Items),
    aggregate_all(max(Width),Width,(items(_,prodName(Name),_,_),string_length(Name,Width)),Name_Width),
    Name_field_width is Name_Width + 1,
    foldl(add_detail_line(width(Name_field_width)),Items,"",Detail).

print_all_products(Report) :-
    header(Header),
    items_detail(Detail),
    footer(Footer),
    atomic_list_concat([Header,Detail,Footer], Report).

print_all_products :-
    print_all_products(Report),
    write(Report).

:- begin_tests(formatted_report).

test(1) :-
    print_all_products(Report),
    with_output_to(atom(Atom),write(Report)),
    assertion( Atom == '\n........................\nAvailable Products\n........................\nName   Qty\nPots    50\nPans    50\nSpoons  50\nForks   50\nKettles 50\nPlates  50\n........................\n' ).

:- end_tests(formatted_report).
```

---

Note: The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63315677/1243762) given by Peter is the customary way to do the formatting, but as I noted, that drives me nuts. Even so, that is the way I would do it in a production environment.

I gave this answer because the OP noted they were looking for a way to do it using predicates like forall/2 or foreach/2. Granted neither of them is used in this answer but the intent of using a more functional approach is used.

If the question was more open ended I would have given a answer using DCGs.

Comment: Try it with a table of 10’000 entries, does it work?

Answer (score 1):

[format/2](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=format/2) ... for putting things in neat columns, use `~|`, `~t`, `~+`.

`~|` sets a tab to "here", `~t` inserts fill characters, `~+` advances the tab beyond the last "here" (`~|`) and distributes the fill characters. So,

```
format("(~|~`.t~d~5+)~n", [123])
```

produces `(..123)` -- the format string right-justifies the number with `.`s in a width of 5, surrounded by parentheses.

Comment: Using `~t`, `~|` and `~+` with format/2,3 drives me nuts.

Comment: @GuyCoder Me too

Comment: `~|` sets a tab to "here", `~t` inserts fill characters, `~+` advances the tab beyond the last "here" (`~|`) and distributes the fill characters. So,  `format('(~|~\`.t~d~5+)~n', [123])` produces `(..123)` ... the number is right-justified with `.`s in a width of 5.

Comment: Could you add many more real world examples an make a Wiki of it on the SWI-Prolog forum? :)  I would but it might be I would go nuts trying.

Comment: @GuyCoder - I added my real world example to my answer; you can upvote it if you wish. ;)

Comment: Another explanation is here (together with my answer, slightly expanded): https://swi-prolog.discourse.group/t/using-format-to-align-text-left-and-numbers-right/3304/2

Answer (score 1):

You are asking for SQL-style tabular output and yes, that should be in the language as basic predicate set since when Reagan was prez. I don't know what's going on. It's probably out there in a library though (but where is the library?)

Meanwhile, here is the "failure driven-loop" using some of my personal toolbox goodies, but it uses SWI Prolog:

In file `printthem.pl`:

```
:- use_module(library('heavycarbon/strings/string_of_spaces.pl')).
:- use_module(library('heavycarbon/strings/string_overwriting.pl')).

items(itemId('P01'),prodName('Pots'),stockOty(50),price(8200)).
items(itemId('P02'),prodName('Pans'),stockOty(50),price(400)).
items(itemId('P03'),prodName('Spoons'),stockOty(50),price(200)).
items(itemId('P04'),prodName('Forks'),stockOty(50),price(120)).
items(itemId('P05'),prodName('Kettles'),stockOty(50),price(500)).
items(itemId('P06'),prodName('Plates'),stockOty(50),price(60)).

printthem :-
   % ideally these should be built by getting max(length) over a column - hardcode for now!
   string_of_spaces(5,SpacesId),
   string_of_spaces(10,SpacesName),
   string_of_spaces(4,SpacesQuant),
   string_of_spaces(6,SpacesPrice),
   % begin failure-driven loop!
   items(itemId(Id),prodName(Name),stockOty(Quant),price(Price)), % backtrack over this until no more solutions
   % transform data into string; see predicate format/2;
   % capture output instead of letting it escape to STDOUT
   with_output_to(string(TxtId),format("~q",[Id])),
   with_output_to(string(TxtName),format("~q",[Name])),
   with_output_to(string(TxtQuant),format("~d",[Quant])),
   with_output_to(string(TxtPrice),format("~d",[Price])),
   % formatting consist in overwriting the space string with the data-carrying string
   string_overwriting(SpacesId,TxtId,       1,TxtIdFinal),
   string_overwriting(SpacesName,TxtName,   1,TxtNameFinal),
   string_overwriting(SpacesQuant,TxtQuant, 1,TxtQuantFinal),
   string_overwriting(SpacesPrice,TxtPrice, 1,TxtPriceFinal),
   % output the line
   format("~s~s~s~s\n",[TxtIdFinal,TxtNameFinal,TxtQuantFinal,TxtPriceFinal]),
   % close the loop
   fail.
```

The above is just an *ébauche*. Improvements are possible in several distinct directions.

The modules loaded via

```
:- use_module(library('heavycarbon/strings/string_of_spaces.pl')).
:- use_module(library('heavycarbon/strings/string_overwriting.pl')).
```

can be obtained from GitHub [here](https://github.com/dtonhofer/prolog_notes/tree/master/code). You will have to grab several files and arrange them appropriately. Read the script [`load_and_test_script.pl`](https://github.com/dtonhofer/prolog_notes/blob/master/code/load_and_test_script.pl). Don't mind the mess, this is work in progress.

If everything has been set up correctly:

```
?- [printthem].
true.

?- printthem.
 'P01' 'Pots'    50  8200 
 'P02' 'Pans'    50  400  
 'P03' 'Spoons'  50  200  
 'P04' 'Forks'   50  120  
 'P05' 'Kettles' 50  500  
 'P06' 'Plates'  50  60   
false.
```

Comment: Meanwhile my unit tests reveal that SWI-Prolog has acquired additional nondeterminism between 8.3.4 and 8.3.5. Interesting ... I need to get to the bottom of THAT.

Comment: And speaking of Reagan, I notice that the book ["Strategic Computing"](https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/strategic-computing) about the computing side of the "Strategic Defense Initiative" mentions Prolog exactly once and is not even in the index once whereas LISP gets mentioned twice on every page or so. Parochial! Ok, back to work.

Comment: You don't need `string_of_spaces` ... just use `format` (see my answer). `Format` also makes it easy to right-justify items.

Comment: @GuyCoder Jeez sometimes one just wants to get things done within 10 minutes.

Comment: @GuyCoder After 30 years of dev, I have seen a lot. That's why we have test cases