# How to print out all the facts in prolog

Tags: prolog

I have a set of rules and a function which prints out all the animals as follows.

```
animal(dog).
animal(cat).
animal(rat).

printAnimals :-
  animal(X),
  format("~q",[X]).
```

In the terminal when i type out `printAnimals.` I only get dog. cat and rat only get printed when i press the `;` button. How do i modify this function to print out all the animals without having to press `;`.

Comment: No need to write your own printAnimals. Try `?- listing(animal/1).`

Comment: You probably want to separate the items: `format("~q~n", [X])`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your approach, backtracking is interactive and occurs at the REPL (the Prolog toplevel) by pressing `;`.

You have to collect all the animals either by using one of the meta-predicates

- [`findall/3`](https://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=findall/3)
- [`bagof/3`](https://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=bagof/3)

to create a list of animals which can then be printed using [`maplist/2`](https://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=maplist/2).

You can also use [`forall/2`](https://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=forall/2) to emit side-effects as animals are collected.

Or you can write a failure-driven loop:

```
printAllAnimals :-
  animal(X),
  format("~q",[X]),
  fail. % failure causes backtracking to animal(X), which collects the next animal
```